# C# datagridview right click select row and show menu to call a form for edit the row selected

Tags: sql-server, winforms, datagrid, edit, right-click

i search every where but i can not find a solution to my problem
i just  wondering how to make a right click menu in data grid view to edit the data from SQL

this is my code for creating a context menu for right click but i cannot call a form to get the data from the row that were i right click it and edit the data..

```
public void Rightclick()
   {
       ContextMenu Rmnu = new ContextMenu();
       MenuItem mnuCCS = new MenuItem("Change Class Size");
       MenuItem mnuDeactv = new MenuItem("Deactivate");

       mnuCCS.Click += new EventHandler(radGridView_Class_View_Click);
       mnuDeactv.Click += new EventHandler(radGridView_Class_View_Click);

       Rmnu.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { mnuCCS, mnuDeactv });
       radGridView_Class_View.ContextMenu = Rmnu;



   }
   private void radGridView_Class_View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Rightclick();
   }
```

i want to create a form for edit... that get the data from datagrid and edit it.. using the right click menu...

can somebody help me.. thanks...

Comment: Do you want to open an edit form for the record that you have right-clicked on?

Comment: yes.. that's what i want to do.. please help...

Answer (score 3):

I think, you should look into this [**MSDN-article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.contextmenustrip.aspx). It shows how to use a [ContextMenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx) for your problem.

Sample below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Test-Data
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetTestData();

        // Add menu
        AddContextMenu(dataGridView1);

        // remember mouse location
        AddMouseEnterEvent();
    }

    private DataTable GetTestData()
    {
        DataTable tab = new DataTable();
        DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("col1");
        DataColumn c2 = new DataColumn("col2");
        tab.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { c1, c2 });
        DataRow r1 = tab.NewRow(); r1[c1] = "cell 1"; r1[c2] = "cell 2";
        DataRow r2 = tab.NewRow(); r2[c1] = "cell 3"; r2[c2] = "cell 4";
        tab.Rows.Add(r1);
        tab.Rows.Add(r2);

        return tab;
    }

    private void AddContextMenu(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var strip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        var menu1 = strip.Items.Add("Change Class Size");
        var menu2 = strip.Items.Add("Deactivate");

        menu1.Click += new EventHandler(menu1_Click);
        menu2.Click += new EventHandler(menu2_Click);
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            column.ContextMenuStrip = strip;
        }
    }

    DataGridViewCellEventArgs mouseLocation;
    void AddMouseEnterEvent()
    {
        dataGridView1.CellMouseEnter += (s,e) => { mouseLocation = e; };
    }

    void menu2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[mouseLocation.RowIndex].Cells[mouseLocation.ColumnIndex];
        // do something stupid
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    void menu1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[mouseLocation.RowIndex].Cells[mouseLocation.ColumnIndex];
        // do something even more stupid
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: hi ralf.w. I try to understand the functions but i cannot interpret it.... i'm just a beginner hope you understand... Do you have some idea how to do it?  thanks..

Comment: @user1207105 : sample added (would be nice to get my sample as accepted)

Comment: hi again ralf.w. tank you for your example code i modify it a little and it works for me.. POWER UP!!!!